# Given degree sequence of Graph G, find the number of edges in its line graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let the degree sequence of a graph G be $d_1, d_2, ....d_V$. In Line graph of G L(G), edge of G becomes vertex of L(G). If the incident vertices on an edge of G has degree $d_i, d_j$ then corresponding edge which is vertex in L(G) has degree $d_i-1+d_j-1=d_i+d_j-2$.

So degree sequence of L(G) $:= d_1+d_2-2, d_2+d_3-2, ......d_{v-1}+d_v-2$

Number of edges of L(G) = half the degree sum = $\frac {1}{2}\{d_1+d_v+2(d_2+d_3+d_4+...d_{v-1})-2(v-1) \}=\frac {1}{2}\{2(2E)-d_1-d_v-2v+2\},$ where E is number of edges of G.

How to proceed now? Please have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your idea of using the "sum of the degrees is twice the edges" formula is a good one, you need to be a bit more careful with how you add things up.  Let's work through an example with the below graph

[image: Graph]

Here there's five lines, which I'll denote by $\ell_{12}, \ell_{14},$ and so on.  The sum of the degrees is 
\begin{eqnarray*}
& & \deg(\ell_{12})+\deg(\ell_{14})+\deg(\ell_{23})+\deg(\ell_{24})+\deg(\ell_{34}) \\
&=& (d_1+d_2-2)+(d_1+d_4-2)+(d_2+d_3-2)+(d_2+d_4-2)+(d_3+d_4-2) \\
&=& 2d_1 + 3d_2 + 2 d_3 + 3d_4 - 10
\end{eqnarray*}

---

One key thing to notice here is that we're adding up not just $(d_1+d_2-2)$, $(d_2+d_3-2)$, etc.  Instead, we're adding up the degrees for every single edge in the graph.  This means that some vertex degrees are being added many times.  In fact, for any vertex $v_i$, we're including its degree as part of the sum of $d_i$ different edges.  In the above example, vertex $2$ had degree $3$, so when we added up all the edge degrees we included $d_2$ a total of $3$ times.  More generally, when we add up the edge degrees, we're including $d_i$ (the degree of vertex $i$) a total of $d_i$ different times.

So the analogue of "$2d_1+3d_2+2d_3+3d_4$" is 
$$d_1(d_1)+d_2 (d_2) +d_3 (d_3) +\dots+d_v (d_v) = d_1^2+d_2^2+\dots+d_v^2.$$

The $-10$ part corresponds to subtracting off a $2$ for each edge in the graph.  So more generally we'd be subtracting off $2|E|$.  This means that we have

\begin{eqnarray*}
2 (\# \textrm{ edges in } E(G)) &=& \sum_{(i,j) \in E(G)} \deg(\ell_{ij}) \\
&=& \sum_{i=1}^v d_i^2 - 2|E| \\
&=& \sum_{i=1}^v d_i^2 - d_i
\end{eqnarray*}
Where for the last step I used that the number of edges was half the sum of the vertex degrees.

Comment: As a general rule, when you feel like you're getting stuck somewhere or aren't sure what you have so far is right, a good idea is to try working through a small example where you can get your hands on everything concretely.  This is particularly true in graph theory, where it's easy to draw and work with a graph with only $4$ or $5$ vertices, just to see what's going on.  It's a lot easier to guess the formula I got *after* working through the example I gave than before.

Comment: Got it sir thank you. I have recently started graph theory.

Comment: Note the edit above.  Also, here's a different way of thinking about things you might want to consider.  Each edge in the line graph corresponds to two edges in the original graph sharing a vertex.  For example, in the above graph we have the edges $(1,2)$ and $(2,3)$, which share the vertex $2$ in common.  How many other vertices in the line graph come from "Vertex $2$ in common"?  In general, if a vertex has degree $d_i$, how many edges in the line graph come from "sharing vertex $i$ in common"?  If you think about that, you may be able to get an alternative approach to the same formula.

Comment: I think it is $d_1C2+d_2C2+....d_vCv$(same answer as above). $(k_1i)---(k_2 j)$ is an edge in L(G) means for vertex (ij) we have 2 vertices k1, k2(2 edges per edge in L(G))